# Reactjs - Passing API data as props for Autocomplete component (Material-UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, autocomplete, material-ui

I am a beginner in Reactjs. I am trying to implement the [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#Asynchronous.js) component provided by material-ui. I want to pass the API link as a prop to the element. But how to pass the json label name as a prop to be used in "getOptionLabel"? For example, If we consider [this API link](https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q='Sherlock') which returns TV Show names, we need to use SHOW.NAME to access the name of the show.

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.show.name}
```

Here, the dynamic part is 'show.name'. How to pass this as prop? I tried doing

```
const label = 'show.name'
```

and then

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
```

But his wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the props in the function.
You could do something like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const someData = [{
    name: "abc"
  }]
  return ( <
    Autocomplete myOptions={someData} />
  );
}


export default function ComboBox(props) {
  return ( <
    Autocomplete id = "combo-box-demo"
    options = {
      props.myOptions
    }
    getOptionLabel = {
      (option) => option.name
    }
    style = {
      {
        width: 300
      }
    }
    renderInput = {
      (params) => < TextField { ...params
      }
      label = "Combo box"
      variant = "outlined" / >
    }
    />
  );
}
```

See it live [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/some-example-p3fyn)